# How can I avoid value errors when using numpy.random.multinomial?

Tags: python, numpy, random, numerical-stability

When I use this random generator: [`numpy.random.multinomial`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html), I keep getting:

```
ValueError: sum(pvals[:-1]) > 1.0
```

I am always passing the output of this softmax function:

```
def softmax(w, t = 1.0):
    e = numpy.exp(numpy.array(w) / t)
    dist = e / np.sum(e)
    return dist
```

except now that I am getting this error, I also added this for the parameter (`pvals`):

```
while numpy.sum(pvals) > 1:
    pvals /= (1+1e-5)
```

but that didn't solve it.  What is the right way to make sure I avoid this error?

EDIT: here is function that includes this code

```
def get_MDN_prediction(vec):
    coeffs = vec[::3]
    means = vec[1::3]
    stds = np.log(1+np.exp(vec[2::3]))
    stds = np.maximum(stds, min_std)
    coe = softmax(coeffs)
    while np.sum(coe) > 1-1e-9:
        coe /= (1+1e-5)
    coeff = unhot(np.random.multinomial(1, coe))
    return np.random.normal(means[coeff], stds[coeff])
```

Comment: Have you checked all the values are finite?

Comment: What is the value of `pvals.sum()` as you pass it to `np.random.multinomial`?

Comment: There are a few things you are not showing, like what is the function `A, and the full traceback (including the actual code, `sum(pvals[:-1]) > 1.0` is not here).

Comment: A was numpy.array, I've replaced it.

Comment: If you use `np.random.choice` instead of `np.random.multinomial`, you will get no error and get the same result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also encountered this problem during my language modelling work.

The root of this problem rises from numpy's implicit data casting: the output of my sorfmax() is in `float32` type, however, `numpy.random.multinomial()` will cast the `pval` into `float64` type IMPLICITLY. This data type casting would cause `pval.sum()` exceed 1.0 sometimes due to numerical rounding.

This issue is recognized and posted [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8317)

Answer (score 5):

I know the question is old but since I faced the same problem just now, it seems to me it's still valid. Here's the solution I've found for it:

```
a = np.asarray(a).astype('float64')
a = a / np.sum(a)
b = np.random.multinomial(1, a, 1)
```

I've made the important part bold. If you omit that part the problem you've mentioned will happen from time to time. But if you change the type of array into float64, it will never happen.

Answer (score 2):

Something that few people noticed: a robust version of the softmax can be easily obtained by removing the logsumexp from the values:

```
from scipy.misc import logsumexp

def log_softmax(vec):
    return vec - logsumexp(vec)

def softmax(vec):
    return np.exp(log_softmax(vec))
```

Just check it:

```
print(softmax(np.array([1.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.1])))
```

Simple, isn't it?

Comment: I get a sum of 1.0000000000000002 for `softmax(np.array([1/20.]*20)).sum()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `softmax` implementation I was using is not stable enough for the values I was using it with.  As a result, sometimes the output has a sum greater than `1` (e.g. `1.0000024...`).

This case should be handled by the while loop.  But sometimes the output contains NaNs, in which case the loop is never triggered, and the error persists.

Also, `numpy.random.multinomial` doesn't raise an error if it sees a NaN.

Here is what I'm using right now, instead:

```
def softmax(vec):
    vec -= min(A(vec))
    if max(vec) > 700:
        a = np.argsort(vec)
        aa = np.argsort(a)
        vec = vec[a]
        i = 0
        while max(vec) > 700:
            i += 1
            vec -= vec[i]
        vec = vec[aa]
    e = np.exp(vec)
    return e/np.sum(e)

def sample_multinomial(w):
    """
       Sample multinomial distribution with parameters given by softmax of w
       Returns an int    
    """
    p = softmax(w)
    x = np.random.uniform(0,1)
    for i,v in enumerate(np.cumsum(p)):
        if x < v: return i
    return len(p)-1 # shouldn't happen...
```