# numpy.random.multinomial bad outputs?

Tags: python, numpy, random, numerical-stability

I have this function:

```
import numpy as np 
def unhot(vec):
    """ takes a one-hot vector and returns the corresponding integer """
    assert np.sum(vec) == 1    # this assertion shouldn't fail, but it did...
    return list(vec).index(1)
```

that I call on the output of a call to:

```
numpy.random.multinomial(1, coe)
```

and I got an assertion error at some point when I ran it.  How is this possible?  Isn't the output of numpy.random.multinomial guaranteed to be a one-hot vector?

Then I removed the assertion error, and now I have:

```
ValueError: 1 is not in list
```

Is there some fine-print I am missing, or is this just broken?

Comment: what are you passing as vec?

Comment: What is `coe`, is it one-dimensional?

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun, `vec` is the ouput from `np.random.multinomial`, as stated in the question.

Comment: I can't repeat this behavior (you have `coe.sum() == 1` I assume) for any value of `coe`.  What version of numpy are you running?

Comment: Also, I'd recommend replacing `list(vec).index(1)` with `vec.argmax()`, which is the same in the case that `1` is the max value of the array.  For identical behavior but slower performance (but still much faster than converting to list) use `np.where(vec==1)[0][0]`

Comment: askewchan - thanks.  I am trying to ensure that the sum is leq 1, but I am having problems there as well, see my other question: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257587/how-can-i-avoid-value-errors-when-using-numpy-random-multinomial)  I guess I should try with python's sum rather than numpy's.

Comment: ebarr - yes, coe is one dimensional.  It is a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is the problem, and I should've realized, because I've encountered it before:

```
np.random.multinomial(1,A([  0.,   0.,  np.nan,   0.]))
```

returns

```
array([0,                    0, -9223372036854775807,0])
```

I was using an unstable softmax implementation that gave the Nans.
Now, I was trying to ensure that the parameters I passed multinomial had a sum <= 1, but I did it like this:

```
coe = softmax(coeffs)
while np.sum(coe) > 1-1e-9:
    coe /= (1+1e-5)
```

and with NaNs in there, the while statement will never even get triggered, I think.

Comment: That large negative number is the int representation of `np.nan` which only works as a float. This still seems like a strange way to make `coe.sum() <=1`.  How do you want `np.nan` to be interpreted? Probably as `0`, or `1`?  If `0`, you can use `np.nansum` to ignore the `nan`: `coe /= np.nansum(coe)`.  If `1`, you'll have to just say `coe[np.isnan] = 1` before `coe /= coe.sum()`.