# np.random.choice: probabilities do not sum to 1

Tags: python, numpy

**how can I use np.random.choice here?**
there is `p` that calculate by some opertation, like :

```
 p=[  1.42836755e-01,   1.42836735e-01  , 1.42836735e-01,   1.42836735e-01
,   4.76122449e-05,   1.42836735e-01  , 4.76122449e-05  , 1.42836735e-01,
   1.42836735e-01,   4.76122449e-05]
```

usually sum p is not exact equal to 1:

```
>>> sum(p)
1.0000000017347
```

I want to make random choice by probabilities=p:

```
>>> np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10], 4, p=p, replace=False)
array([4, 3, 2, 9])
```

this work here! but in the program it has an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    indexs=np.random.choice(range(len(population)), population_number, p=p, replace=False)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1141, in mtrand.RandomState.choice (numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c:17808)
ValueError: probabilities do not sum to 1
```

if I print the `p`:

```
[  4.17187500e-05   2.49937500e-01   4.16562500e-05   4.16562500e-05
   2.49937500e-01   4.16562500e-05   4.16562500e-05   4.16562500e-05
   2.49937500e-01   2.49937500e-01]
```

but it works, in python shell by this `p`:

```
>>> p=[  4.17187500e-05 ,  2.49937500e-01   ,4.16562500e-05  , 4.16562500e-05,
   2.49937500e-01  , 4.16562500e-05  , 4.16562500e-05  , 4.16562500e-05,
   2.49937500e-01   ,2.49937500e-01]
>>> np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10], 4, p=p, replace=False)
array([ 9, 10,  2,  5])
```

**UPDATE**
I have tested it by precision=15:

```
 np.set_printoptions(precision=15)
 print(p)
[  2.499375625000002e-01   2.499375000000000e-01   2.499375000000000e-01
   4.165625000000000e-05   4.165625000000000e-05   4.165625000000000e-05
   4.165625000000000e-05   4.165625000000000e-05   2.499375000000000e-01
   4.165625000000000e-05]
```

testing:

```
>>> p=np.array([  2.499375625000002e-01   ,2.499375000000000e-01   ,2.499375000000000e-01,
   4.165625000000000e-05   ,4.165625000000000e-05,   4.165625000000000e-05,
   4.165625000000000e-05  , 4.165625000000000e-05 ,  2.499375000000000e-01,
   4.165625000000000e-05])
>>> np.sum(p)
1.0000000000000002
```

**how fix this to use  np.random.choice ?**

Comment: Try printing `[repr(x) for x in p]` and, if `p` is a numpy array, `p.dtype`. Despite the common belief it is not always possible to recreate a sequence of floats just from the output of `print`.

Comment: thx. how can I use  np.random.choice here?

Comment: It works for me. You need to work harder to create a [mcve].

Comment: >>> p=np.array([0.1999600079984003, 0.1999600079984003, 0.1999600079984003, 3.9992001599680064e-05, 0.1999600079984003, 3.9992001599680064e-05, 3.9992001599680064e-05, 0.1999600079984003, 3.9992001599680064e-05, 3.9992001599680064e-05])
>>> np.sum(p)
0.99999999999999978

Comment: I do not see why you keep posting examples that **do not** trigger the error. They are not useful to solve your problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/6131) with numpy. The random choice function checks for the sum of the probabilities using a given tolerance ([here the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.9.x/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1082))

The solution is to normalize the probabilities by dividing them by their sum if the sum is close enough to 1

Example:

```
>>> p=[  1.42836755e-01,   1.42836735e-01  , 1.42836735e-01,   1.42836735e-01
,   4.76122449e-05,   1.42836735e-01  , 4.76122449e-05  , 1.42836735e-01,
   1.42836735e-01,   4.79122449e-05]
>>> sum(p) 
1.0000003017347 # over tolerance limit
>>> np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10], 4, p=p, replace=False)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#23>", line 1, in <module>
    np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10], 4, p=p, replace=False)
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1417, in mtrand.RandomState.choice (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:15985)
ValueError: probabilities do not sum to 1
```

With normalization:

```
>>> p = np.array(p)
>>> p /= p.sum()  # normalize
>>> np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10], 4, p=p, replace=False)
array([8, 4, 1, 6])
```

Comment: thx but dosenot work. ValueError: probabilities do not sum to 1. what to do ?

Comment: @pdshah have you tried normalizing the probabilities by `p /= p.sum()`?

Comment: yes: >>> p=np.array([0.1999600079984003, 0.1999600079984003, 0.1999600079984003, 3.9992001599680064e-05, 0.1999600079984003, 3.9992001599680064e-05, 3.9992001599680064e-05, 0.1999600079984003, 3.9992001599680064e-05, 3.9992001599680064e-05])
>>> np.sum(p)
0.99999999999999978

>>> p /= p.sum()
>>> np.sum(p)
1.0000000000000002

Comment: @pdshah ok the sum is still not exactly one, but does `np.random.choice` work?

Comment: First thing I thought to do as well. but it did not work

Comment: This may not work due to round-off errors accumulated due to division. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71400320/6087087 for a definitive solution.

Answer (score 18):

Convert it to float64:

```
p = np.asarray(p).astype('float64')
p = p / np.sum(p)
np.random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 10], 4, p=p, replace=False)
```

This was inspired by another post: [How can I avoid value errors when using numpy.random.multinomial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23257587/how-can-i-avoid-value-errors-when-using-numpy-random-multinomial)

Comment: IMO this should have more votes. None of the answers worked for my case when my  p = [1,1,1], this one did. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

> ValueError: probabilities do not sum to 1

This is a known numpy bug. This error happens when numpy can’t handle float operations precise enough.  Sometimes, probabilities will sum to something like 0.9999999999997 or 1.0000000000003. They will break np.random.choice().

There is a workaround: [np.random.multinomial()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.multinomial.html). This method handles probabilities more elegantly without the need to be exactly 1.0.

> pvals : sequence of floats, length p Probabilities of each of the p
>   different outcomes. These should sum to 1 (however, the last element
>   is always assumed to account for the remaining probability, as long as
>   sum(pvals[:-1]) <= 1).

For example, I have some choices and normalized_weights associated with the choices.

np.random.multinomial() choose 20 times based on the normalized_weights and returns how many times each choice is chosen.

```
choices = [......]
weights = np.array([......])
normalized_weights = weights / np.sum(weights)

number_of_choices = 20
resample_counts = np.random.multinomial(number_of_choices,
                                        normalized_weights)

chosen = []
resample_index = 0
for resample_count in resample_counts:
    for _ in range(resample_count):
        chosen.append(choices[resample_index])
    resample_index += 1
```

Comment: It won't always add up

Answer (score 3):

One way to see the difference is:

```
numpy.set_printoptions(precision=15)
print(p)
```

This will perhaps show you that your `4.17187500e-05` is actually `4.17187500005e-05`. See [the manual here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html).

Comment: thx. I added more comment on the post. how to fix this problem ?