# Normalizing numpy array sum to 1.0 fails on Intel CPU and also Colab

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm trying various ways to normalize array sum to 1, but it fails. E.g. the following code fails on Intel CPU and also Colab:

```
import numpy as np

a = 0.99
choice = 0
g = np.ones((9,)) * (1.0 - a)/8
g[choice] = a
print(np.sum(g), g)
g = g / np.sum(g) 
print(np.sum(g), g)
assert(np.sum(g) == 1.0)
```

Comment: Linked with floating point artihmetic, there are a numerous other posts about that on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=floating+point+arithmetic

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/floating-point/info

Comment: @Nathan that's an excellent point! But then the answer on this page is wrong:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539431/np-random-choice-probabilities-do-not-sum-to-1 that's the problem that I'm trying to solve. What should I do?!!

Comment: Ok, fair enough, maybe that answer isn't wrong! I'll try taking out my assertion or modifying it to see what happens.